# How to store information on an Xcode picker?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, picker

I'm new to Xcode.

I'm trying to make my second iPhone application, it's based on **alcoholic drinks**, how to prepare them (for example: Sex on the beach, Daikiri, etc.)

My question is how can I change the **pickers** options and store information in each one of them.

When the user chooses a specific drink from the picker load up the information..

How can i do this ?

Comment: have you got the solution ? If yes, please accept the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UIPickerView` controller to perform this task.

Take UIPickerView controller in the `xib` of viewcontrller in which you want to do this task.

Then specify `UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource` and `IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerview` in your viewcontroller.h file.

Then use delegate methods of UIPickerView as follows ;

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
{
    return 1; 
}
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    return [yourArray count]; //give array that contains the alcoholic drinks values....
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    return [yourArray objectAtIndex:row]; //display alcoholic drinks in picker....

}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
  //display whichever information you want to display after selection in picker
}
```